# how to build react-native sample?

Tags: react-native, sample

What I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native
cd react-native
npm install
```

Result:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/wv/.nvmasdf/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/node" "/Users/wv/.nvmasdf/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! path /Users/wv/work/react-native/react-native/node_modules/babel/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/micromatch/node_modules/extglob/node_modules/ansi-green/node_modules/ansi-wrap
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/wv/work/react-native/react-native/node_modules/babel/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/anymatch/node_modules/micromatch/node_modules/extglob/node_modules/ansi-green/node_modules/ansi-wrap' -> '/Users/wv/work/react-native/react-native/node_modules/ansi-wrap'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/wv/work/react-native/react-native/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do? not sure what you mean by 'sample' but try following the getting started guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html